# Stored procedure issue? Please take a looK?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

For some very strange reason I'm getting an error when I try to execute the stored procedure. I'm not including the whole thing because it's quite long but maybe someone will have an idea why I keep seeing an error. So I had one stored procedure which pulls about 12 different items from a table. I needed to expand it to 23 items. The first one works perfectly, as a matter of fact I'm pulling the same data from both and no issues with the first one.

```
,OtherInsur
,CASE
    WHEN HighestID = 1 then ''Home Schooled''
    WHEN HighestID = 2 then ''Grammar School''
    WHEN HighestID = 3 then ''High School''
    WHEN HighestID = 4 then ''GED''
    WHEN HighestID = 5 then ''Technical School''
    WHEN HighestID = 6 then ''Masters''
    WHEN HighestID = 7 then ''PHD''
    WHEN HighestID = 8 then ''Other''
END as HighestID
,HighestOtherDesc
,MemLocator
FROM dbo.[tblTest_Customers]'
```

the error says "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Mast'.
Incorrect synthax near "Mast'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd bet the variable holding your dynamic SQL script is too short. For example, if it's `varchar(1000)` and your script is 1500 characters long, it will stop at 1000. So "Mast" must be at the end of your string, and therefore the script is incomplete and invalid.

Comment: You are the damn @joeEnos. Yes that is correct, it was at varchar(1000). thank you a lot! I've been sitting here scratching my head.